# how can i modify Some controls with similar tags at onec in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a VB code here and i wanna convert it into C# format, i'm new in C#. can anybody help me?

here is VB code:

```
  Dim o As Object
            For Each o In Me.Controls
                If o.tag= "1" Then
                    o.BackColor = Color.Blue
                End If
```

i want to modify an option in some of my form's controls with tag "1". how can i do that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes rather heavy use of vb.net's support for dynamic typing.  Avoid using sample code like that.

```
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls) {
            if (ctl.Tag.ToString() == "1") {
                ctl.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want in C#

```
        foreach (Control o in this.Controls)
        {
            if (o.Tag.ToString() == "1")
                o.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Me.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    var o = Me.Controls[i];
    if (o.tag == "1")
        o.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```